# Postgres - Export error: Failed to execute pg_dumpall

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

i'm using PostgreSQL and i want to export my table in my database usng phppgadmin But the process does not allow me to do so and i'm getting this error

```
Export error: Failed to execute pg_dumpall (given path in your conf/config.inc.php : /usr/bin/pg_dumpall). Please, fix this path in your configuration and relog.
```

What should i do?

Comment: what tool are you using to export your database? you aren't calling pg_dumall directly aren't you?

Comment: you should use pg_dump  with aditional parameters  -Fp -t "mytable" --inserts

Comment: i'm using phppgadmin to export my table

Comment: Find config.inc.php inside your phppgadmin and change  /usr/bin/pg_dumpall to correct locvation. Linux find / -name pg_dumpall

Comment: what location should i set?

Comment: see this link: (https://github.com/xzilla/phppgadmin/commit/83e0f7de9d2ebac3949fb66709b582a40a38aab0)